# Lowercase everything after firts appearance of the character in a string in JS

Tags: javascript, string

Lowercase everything after firts appearance of the character in a string in JS

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is splitting the string at `"."`, then convert the last part `.toLowerCase()` and finally `.join()` everything back together.

```js
const t = 'qwery.ABC.ABC';

const parts = t.split(".");
console.log(parts.slice(0, -1).join(".") + "." + parts[parts.length - 1].toLowerCase());
```

---

One could argue whether that would actually be a *cleaner* variant. What usually isn't a bad idea for code readability is writing a utility function for that use case.

```
const t = "qwery.ABC.ABC";

const lastBitToLowerCase = (text, separator) => {
  const parts = t.split(separator);
  return `${parts.slice(0, -1).join(separator)}${separator}${parts[
    parts.length - 1
  ].toLowerCase()}`;
};

const result = lastBitToLowerCase(t, "."); // "qwery.ABC.abc"
```

Comment: Instead of adding the last `.` manually with `+` operator, you can also use this: `let parts = t.split(".");
parts = parts.slice(0, -1).concat(parts.at(-1).toLowerCase()).join('.')`

Answer (score 2):

One option is using regular expression:

```
str.replace(/\.([^.]*?)$/, (m) => m.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex using negative lookahead:

```js
const re = /\.((?:.(?!\.))+)$/;
const inputs = [
"qwerty.ABC.ABC",
"yuiop.uu",
"QWERT.YUIOP"
];

inputs.forEach(input => {
   const result = input.replace(re, x => x.toLowerCase());
   console.log(input, "-->", result);
});
```

Regex described here: https://regexr.com/6qk6r